How to compute $RA$ in $O(n^2)$ operations instead of $O(n^3)$ using Householder reflection
I am currently writing a program that performs QR decomposition on a matrix $A$.
The guidelines to my assignment tell me that once I calculate $R$ using Householder reflections, there is a way to compute $RA$ using $O(n^2)$ operations instead of the usual $O(n^3)$.
I am struggling to come up with this method and was wondering if anybody knew it.
